# Firebase Analytics API and other data API's

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-analytics

I'm wanting to interact with my data from Firebase Analytics within my application. I want to be able to use the monthly active users or current active users. Does Firebase offer an API for analytics data? If not, what other API's are available? Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542637/can-i-get-firebase-analytics-data-using-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get firebase analytics data using query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542637/can-i-get-firebase-analytics-data-using-query)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like in order to access Firebase Analytics data, you export it to BigQuery. This is working for me and is automated.