# Can bigquery or Firebase analytics data acessible from ios app side programmatically?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have Firebase analytics data and enabled BigQuery. But I have a requirement to validate the number of events and screens at app side under automated UI testing. Anyway to access  and validate the Firebase analytics data at ios app side programmatically either in swift or objective c?

Answer (score 2):

There is no API to retrieve Google Analytics data through Firebase. See [Can I get firebase analytics data using query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542637/can-i-get-firebase-analytics-data-using-query)

There is also no API for BigQuery to allow secure access directly from your client-side app. That would be a significant security risk, as you'd be exposing data about all of your users to all of your users.

The usual way to implement functionality is to create a custom endpoint (either using a server you already have, or Cloud Functions for Firebase) that exposes just the information your clients need access